# Override admin submit_button() functionality

Tags: buttons, input

I would like to be able to override the `submit_button()` functionality, so that I can display it as a `<button></button>` element.

Is that possible? I saw that the source is in wp-admin/template.php, but not sure what the flexibility is of overriding that.

Comment: What does “display it as a element” mean? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, my html was rendered so it wasn't visible. Edited question - i imagine that was quite confusing!